# Define Custom Data Type

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

I'm trying to define a own custom datatype by extending SimpleType. I want to bind it against an Input Field. But something I must be doing wrong because my custom type is ignored completely.

Here my snipplets:

```
sap.ui.define([
    "sap/ui/model/SimpleType",
    "sap/ui/model/ValidateException"
], function (SimpleType, ValidateException) {
    "use strict";

    return SimpleType.extend("my.model.customFloat", {

        formatValue: function(oValue) {

            return parseFloat(oValue);
        },
        parseValue: function(oValue) {


            if(isNaN(parseFloat(oValue))) {
                return 0.0
            }

            return parseFloat(oValue);
        },
        validateValue: function(oValue) {
            if(isNaN(parseFloat(oValue))) {
                throw new ValidateException(oValue+" is not a valid decimal value");
            }
        }

    });

});
```

and in my view.xml I have used my custom type in this way.

```
<Input value="{ path:'draftModel>SomeCustomValue', type: 'my.model.customFloat'}" change="onEditDoSomething"/>
```

But it doesn't work. When I type something and want to Debug parseValue, formatValue or validateValue, the methods are never been called. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will need to load your custom type somewhere as well.

Trying adding "my/model/customFloat" to the define section of your controller. There's no need to turn it into an alias, e.g.:

```
sap.ui.define([
        "sap/ui/model/SimpleType",
        "sap/ui/model/ValidateException",
        "my/model/customFloat"
    ], function (SimpleType, ValidateException) {
        "use strict";
        ...
```